# Using post commit hook to export in VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, export, visualsvn-server, post-commit

What is the easiest way to use post-commit hook with VisualSVN Server to export from the repository to a directory for staging / testing after a developer commits his changes?

Answer (score 5):

Do the following in the **VisualSVN Server Manager** MMC console:

1. Select your **repository**
2. Right click **Properties**
3. Select the **Hooks** tab
4. Select the **post-commit hook**
5. Click the **Edit** button. Enter a line like this into the **textbox**:

   ```
   "%VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\svn.exe" export https://svn.yourserver.com:4433/svn/YourRepository/Websites/YourWebsite/ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourWebsite --quiet --non-interactive --force --username <youruser> --password <yourpassword>
   ```
6. Click **Ok**.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find your SVN server installation directory (I have `C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin`).
2. Drop an executable or batch file that does whatever you want in there, and set the post-commit hook to something like this:

   `postcommit.exe "%1" "%2"`

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [svn command-line client](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) you can write a simple post-commit hook script like this:

```
path\to\svn.exe export file:///%1/trunk path\to\where\you\want\to\export\to
```

I'm not sure whether the VisualSVN Server commit hook dialog creates a `.bat` / `.cmd` file or just expects to run the command. If the first, the line above would be enough. If the latter, first create a `.bat` file with the above line in it, then put in the dialog:

```
cmd.exe /C path\to\your\batfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Will do the reading on Cruise Control integration with Subversion - first I've heard of it, though I do hate to throw yet another variable into the mix.

Looked at the VisualSVN link before posting the question, but it doesn't explain how to do anything with VisualSVNServerHooks.exe other than email notification. Can't help but wonder if that is the only feature VisualSVNServerHooks.exe supports, since I could not locate documentation of any other functionality with it on their site, docs, google groups, google search, etc.

Thanks for posting.